# How is stack memory organized?

Tags: c

I just want to make sure I get it right.
Imagine the stack size for any program on my machine is
800 bytes (just example).
Then, following code:

```
void f()
{
char x[300];
char y[300];
char z[300];
char t[300];
}
```

should overflow stack right (because 1200>800)?

Now my question is, is the below approach
an Ok way to defeat above mentioned stack overflow problem?

```
void f()
{
   f1();
   f2();
}
```

where:

```
void f1()
{
    char x[300];
    char y[300];
}

void f2()
{
    char z[300];
    char t[300];
}
```

this way according to my reasoning each function consumes only 600 bytes *(<800)
of stack memory*, so all should be OK. Am I right?

ps. I am not referring to "other" data that could take up space on stack for the sake of this example.

pps. In other words, is this the case, that each time, each function f(), f1(), and f2() get their "instance" of stack?

Comment: yes you are right. f1 uses 600 bytes of stack and upon return releases it. f2 does the same, so at all times you will need less than 800 bytes of stack

Comment: `to defeat above mentioned stack overflow problem` => The two cases are not equivalent. All 4 char-arrays do not coexist at any time in the second case.

Comment: The compiler could always choose to inline those if optimization warrants it and they're good candidates. Never say never.

Comment: @AnirudhR: yes, we can assume I don't need them to co-exist....

Comment: Note: You will use more stack space than just what you need for local variables. There's other bookkeeping that goes on the stack as well.

Comment: How is stack memory organized?  From the bottom up! #CouldntResist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> pps. In other words, is this the case, that each time, each function f(), f1(), and f2() get their "instance" of stack?

When a function is called it will allocate memory for the duration of the call. When the function returns, the memory is returned.

In your example, `f2()` will use the same instance of the stack as `f1()`, but since `f1()` has returned when `f2()` is called, the stack memory used by `f1()` is free to be re-used by `f2()`.

Stacks are allocated per thread, so in a multi-threaded program each thread will have its own stack.

**Edit**

It should be pointed out that the description above is how compilers usually implement local variables. The C standard does not specify that stacks need to be used, but it is the best solution (so far) for environments where an unknown amount of processes/threads need to share a limited amount of memory.

**Edit 2**

Dividing `f` into `f1` and `f2` is one way of reducing the stack memory consumption. Other ways are to allocate memory on the heap (with malloc/free) or statically (static allocation isn't thread-safe, so it reduces portability and reusability and should only be used as a last resort).

> Say I had one local variable defined in f(), what would happen with it, when program entered inside f1()?

It would still be there. You can think of the stack as a pile of papers. Whenever you call a function, the caller adds a paper with the return address and space for the return value. The called function then adds another paper with the local variables.
When a function returns, it removes the top paper (with its local variables) and jots down the return value on the next paper. The calling code reads the return value and removes the top paper, again exposing the paper with the caller's local variables.

Comment: Lindback: Klas, So f(),f1() and f2() all use "one" instance of stack at the same time right? There is only one stack instance? (assuming single threaded app). (that would explain why above approach would work)

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: Then it would make sense why above approach would "save" some memory. Because at single point in time, we are concerned with one instance of stack -- and its memory size.

Comment: Yep, since the stack is the same, after leaving `f1()`, `f2()` will reuse the same memory.

Comment: @Filipe Gonçalves: just out of curiosity: how much memory does then f() consume from stack in the 2nd example? when it calls: f1(), f2(). (also not including other stuff that could take up space)

Comment: The overhead is the return pointer (to tell the program where it called from). Other than that `f()` allocates nothing when it starts (since it has no local variables). When `f1()` is called, 600 bytes are allocated. Those are returned when `f1()` returns. Then the same 600 bytes are allocated when `f2()` is called and again deallocated when `f2()` returns.

Comment: `f()` has no local variables - by the time `f2()` is called, it will consume `f2()` space plus some necessary housekeeping, like frame pointer, etc.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: hm... this is interesting. So in my program, (1) when f() is called 0 bytes is occupied from Stack right? (Excluding other "stuff" that take space), then (2) when f1 is called 600 bytes are taken, and (3) when f3 is called other 600 (previous 600 from f2 are freed). Is this right? And during all these times, all these things are stored/freed inside SAME stack instance right?

Comment: @dmcr_code Yes, that is right (I assume you mean f2 and f1 in (3)).

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: Yes I meant f2 and f1 in (3), sorry it was typo :)

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: In your comment you mean the approach mentioned in the question is the best solution? (also probably you considered comment from WhozCraig .... )?

Comment: Your approach is one way of reducing the stack memory consumption. Other ways are to allocate memory on the heap (with `malloc`/`free`) or statically (static allocation isn't thread-safe, so it reduces portability and reusability).

Comment: +1 on both eh answer and that last comment in particular. Using dynamic memory and therefore specifying in code an alternative storage to the implementation automatic-storage system is not uncommon at all (how many times have we seen "Why does `main()` fault?" only to find `int var[1000][1000];` at the top"). For all you know an embedded system is using the same allocation space for *both*, but at least you're getting a fighting chance. `static` is another. Nice answer.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: Thanks for responses once again, but one question. Now that I think of it, it seems a bit counter intuitive. Say I had one local variable defined in f(), what would happen with it, when program entered inside f1()?

Answer (score 6):

While everyone else throws in their hats concerning "yes it helps", "no it won't", "makes no difference", etc. I'll tell you that what you're asking is so dependent on implementation it is not possible to get a straight universal answer. The variables you're describing are **automatic**, meaning their visibility *and* definition are limited by scope of their function. What goes on behind the curtain is *entirely* platform dependent.

I've already mentioned one case that an implementation could *potentially* have both functions automatic variables occupying memory, namely optimizing out the calls entirely and thus requiring enough occupation memory dedicated to automatic variables to have it *all* in one locality. *You don't know* and honestly you're better off not assuming you need to unless you're writing embedded, kernel or driver code where every byte counts and the platform is a foregone conclusion.

The C standard is very specific in *not* addressing things like this, leaving it to the implementations to fulfill. Search the C99 standard and you'll find the word "stack" exactly *zero* times. That isn't by accident.

That said, if you were designing a *simple* implementation *yourself*, consideration for what you're concerned with would be paramount in design, but unless you're going down that road (or the kernel/driver/embedded side-street where you already know the platform answer), there is simply no concrete way to say "it works this way..." Your implementation would likely simply do as you describe, the proverbial plate stack at the buffet diner. But that by no means can be used to conclude all (or even most) implementations would do the same. So long as they honor the rules put forth by the standard concerning automatic variables, the rest is literally the devil in the details.

Comment: yes I asked this question mainly from implementing it on embedded device point of view

Comment: @dmcr_code if it is embedded you're at the mercy of *their* implementation. I've seen embedded that have separate call-activation and data automatic memory space by-design. I.e. all automatic memory requirements go into one single big chunk of ram at *load* time. It really *does* depends on your back-end how things are done, consult your compiler and hardware, and don't be afraid to ask questions to your vendor concerning the kind of code their tools emit and what should you be concerned with.

Answer (score 1):

Yes splitting up the function will save stack space since while function completes execution (last executable statement in that function is executed) and return's it clears the stack memory it used.

No data will be there (you stored in the char x[300] char y[300]) after the function f1() finishes it's execution

Comment: "But do note that stack and heap are grow in opposite direction so if the stack want's more memory it uses up the common memory which is assigned both heap and stack(towards the heap)" - I don't think memory allocation works like that on modern machines. The heap won't grow into the space allocated for the stack, and the stack definitely won't grow into the space reserved for the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when a compiler execute a program, it occupies or required the memory the current context required. So in first case when your function required more than available space it will throw exception.

While in second case firstly when it try to run main function (ideally) it required no memory.

> [image: main]

so when it tries to run the f1(), which required memory allocation which is not greater than available memory so it will get executed successfully.

> [image: f1]

on returning from function f1() memory will be de-allocated and your complete(ideally) will be available now f2() start getting run which again required the memory.

> [image: f2]

So your program will successfully get executed.

Comment: Thanks for illustrations this is really nice! But one question, now that I think of it, it seems a bit counter intuitive. Say I had one local variable defined in f(), what would happen with it, when program entered inside f1()?

Comment: It would required f1()+ main function variable memory because in f1() you are still in f() scope.

Comment: Yes but how would the memory be managed in that case? When f1() would return, would the space for that variable be again allocated on f()-s stack? Say my code was like ‘void f(){int x; f1(); f2();}‘ what would happen with x memory when program enter f1()?

Comment: It would go this way (a) `f()` started memory:5 (b) `f1()` started memory:5+600 (c) `f1()` completed memory:5 (d) `f2()` started memory:5+600 (e) `f2()` completed memory:5 (f) `f()` completed memory:0

Comment: Hi Zaheer, assuming 5- is the size of the integer right?

Comment: Yes!! the variables in f()